# File download not opening in new tab when setting the file name in .net core api

Tags: c#, api, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I need to download files and open them in a new tab instead of download. The below action works fine when downloading a PDF or image. The file opens in a new tab.

```
    [Route("image/{id}")]
    [Route("view/{id}")]
    [HttpGet]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult GetImage(string id)
    {
        var file = _fileService.Get(id, User);

        return File(file.ByteArray, file.ContentType); 
    }
```

However the file name comes down as the database ID and I want it to come down as the file name. When I set the file name in the file, the file is named correctly but it no longer opens in a new tab. Now it downloads. How can I fix this? Why is it doing this?

```
    [Route("image/{id}")]
    [Route("view/{id}")]
    [HttpGet]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult GetImage(string id)
    {
        var file = _fileService.Get(id, User);

        return File(file.ByteArray, file.ContentType, file.FileName); 
    }
```

Comment: Can't you just make your download open in a new window on frontend?

Comment: thats right, i open it in a new tab on the client with target blank. When i exclude file name on the action it opens in a new tab. When i write file name it downloads.

Comment: You are not downloading a string unless the file is converted to a base64 string.  You probably are download a binary object.

Comment: there are no strings involved here. It's byte array. i'm downloading pdf and jpg. no base64 involved.

Comment: Try writing a file name that ends with "html". I bet the browser will think it is a page and try to open it in a new window instead of downloading. And in case browser 'sees' a non-webpage extension, it will download the thing. You can also play around with content type header.

Comment: When you give it a file name, you do so by indicating that the file is an attachment and the browser saves attachments. If you don't want it to do that, don't give it a file name. So really, the question is why you thought it was necessary to set one in the first place (since the only place it's used is to default the file name in the save dialog)

Comment: My clients that i build software for think that it's necessary for their files to be named correctly.

Comment: @Harry How did you solve this problem?